# Populate Scrapy item with more than one key : value pair

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my code so far:

```
import scrapy

class FcsItem(scrapy.Item): #items.py file
    title = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()

#test.py file below, different file from above

import scrapy
from fcs.items import FcsItem

class FCScrape(scrapy.Spider): 
    name = "FC"
    allowed_domains = ["finalcall.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.finalcall.com/artman/publish/Columns_4/index.shtml"]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = FcsItem()
        divs_title = response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="category-story"]')
            

        for title, link in zip(divs_title.xpath('.//a/text( )'), divs_title.xpath('.//a/@href')):
            item['title'] = title.extract()
            item['link'] = link.extract()

            #I'm actually trying to attach the title as a string as the key and the link as a string as the value in one dictionary.
```

I tried a bunch of different ways, but the problem I keep hitting is not being able to get all the key : value pairs instead of just one. How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Comment: Are you looking for a zip function? https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

How that page is setup, and how you are selecting things, all you're grabbing is one pair, in the form of a tuple.  When you do `zip(divs_title.xpath('.//a/text( )'), divs_title.xpath('.//a/@href')` you return a one item list of the  tag text, and a one item list of the  href content.  You zip the together, and get one item.

The (not-good) solution is to try and keep all these items in a dictionary using a Key:Value pair, as you've requested.  To do so, loop over the "category-story" divs, as they are the articles you want.  You wouldn't need to use items for this, because you don't seem to be using it as an item, anyway:

```
def parse(self, response):
    the_dict = {}
    for article in response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="category-story"]'):
        title = article.xpath('.//a/text( )').extract()
        link = article.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
        the_dict[title] = link
```

The better solution (and what *looks* like your end goal) would be continue using your items, and have a pipeline handle whatever it is you want to do with this content.

```
def parse(self, response):
    for article in response.selector.xpath('//div[@class="category-story"]'):
        item = FcsItem()
        item['title'] = article.xpath('.//a/text( )').extract()
        item['link'] = article.xpath('.//a/@href').extract()
        yield item
```